# activate.bs.scrollspy not being called with a dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have this Table of Contents in a dropdown and I want to use `scrollspy()` to keep track of where I am in the document. I often have hundreds of pages so a dropdown with and `overflow-y: auto;` makes some design sense at this point. However, I also would like to do some other things when the page changes. Notably Change Page # on the dropdown button to the actual page. [according to the documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy-usage) I would use something like the following:

```
$('#myScrollspy').on('activate.bs.scrollspy', function () {
  // do something…
})
```

however, this fails to work. **see the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Mt25g/**
Note: I am using bootstrap 3.0.2 and have tried activate  instead of activate.bs.scrollspy -- for some reason. This is how it "used" to be done.

I've pasted the code below. I am planning on opening an issue on their github page, but since I am rather new to using bootstrap I thought I would appeal for help first. Likely I am doing something wrong? (Code below)

## HTML

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" id="nav_container" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Some WorkSpace</a>

        <div class="pull-right nav">
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary navbar-btn">«</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn navbar-btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id="page_nav">Page: # <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>


<ul class="dropdown-menu" id="page_nav" aria-labelledby="dLbael">


    <li role="presentation" class="pg_nav">
        <a href="#pg-1" title="Page : no page number" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1">1</a>
    </li>
     <li role="presentation" class="pg_nav">
        <a href="#pg-2" title="Page : no page number" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1">2</a>
    </li>
     <li role="presentation" class="pg_nav">
        <a href="#pg-3" title="Page : no page number" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1">3</a>
    </li>




</ul>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary navbar-btn">»</button>
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="btn navbar-btn" disabled="disabled">
                Apply
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning navbar-btn">
                Reset
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<div class="container">
    <section id="pg-1">
        <h3>Bacon</h3>
        <p>
        Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet strip steak boudin shankle jerky meatball corned beef, kielbasa hamburger pastrami prosciutto. Frankfurter andouille jowl prosciutto leberkas brisket t-bone. Tri-tip pancetta cow pastrami pig beef ribs short ribs pork belly ham hock tenderloin turkey andouille. Sausage shoulder strip steak jowl tongue chuck, frankfurter ball tip beef ribs brisket. Spare ribs frankfurter beef ribs pig flank. Pancetta ball tip t-bone spare ribs brisket. Venison ham short ribs tenderloin, meatloaf biltong doner prosciutto pork leberkas pork chop shank tail chuck.
        </p>
        <p>
Pastrami sausage filet mignon leberkas pork bresaola shank corned beef sirloin. Ham hock salami jerky strip steak capicola sirloin venison filet mignon boudin. Sirloin meatball kielbasa pig, drumstick beef ribs tenderloin shank prosciutto corned beef. Ham hock shankle capicola, sausage meatball strip steak ribeye kielbasa.
        </p>
        <p>
Pancetta capicola sirloin, biltong pork loin chuck turducken boudin. Shoulder hamburger andouille pork loin pork belly chicken. Venison ball tip ground round meatloaf rump cow biltong kielbasa tail capicola flank. Tongue andouille strip steak, venison pork belly ham boudin jowl shank capicola pig shankle. Bacon pastrami pancetta, sausage hamburger chicken shank short loin. Swine fatback short loin, ham filet mignon t-bone turkey jowl prosciutto.
        </p>
    </section>
        <section id="pg-2">
        <h3>Sausage</h3>
        <p>
        Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet strip steak boudin shankle jerky meatball corned beef, kielbasa hamburger pastrami prosciutto. Frankfurter andouille jowl prosciutto leberkas brisket t-bone. Tri-tip pancetta cow pastrami pig beef ribs short ribs pork belly ham hock tenderloin turkey andouille. Sausage shoulder strip steak jowl tongue chuck, frankfurter ball tip beef ribs brisket. Spare ribs frankfurter beef ribs pig flank. Pancetta ball tip t-bone spare ribs brisket. Venison ham short ribs tenderloin, meatloaf biltong doner prosciutto pork leberkas pork chop shank tail chuck.
        </p>
        <p>
Pastrami sausage filet mignon leberkas pork bresaola shank corned beef sirloin. Ham hock salami jerky strip steak capicola sirloin venison filet mignon boudin. Sirloin meatball kielbasa pig, drumstick beef ribs tenderloin shank prosciutto corned beef. Ham hock shankle capicola, sausage meatball strip steak ribeye kielbasa.
        </p>
        <p>
Pancetta capicola sirloin, biltong pork loin chuck turducken boudin. Shoulder hamburger andouille pork loin pork belly chicken. Venison ball tip ground round meatloaf rump cow biltong kielbasa tail capicola flank. Tongue andouille strip steak, venison pork belly ham boudin jowl shank capicola pig shankle. Bacon pastrami pancetta, sausage hamburger chicken shank short loin. Swine fatback short loin, ham filet mignon t-bone turkey jowl prosciutto.
        </p>
    </section>
        <section id="pg-3">
        <h3>"Right Lisa"
            <small>Some Magical Animal</small></h3>
        <p>
        Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet strip steak boudin shankle jerky meatball corned beef, kielbasa hamburger pastrami prosciutto. Frankfurter andouille jowl prosciutto leberkas brisket t-bone. Tri-tip pancetta cow pastrami pig beef ribs short ribs pork belly ham hock tenderloin turkey andouille. Sausage shoulder strip steak jowl tongue chuck, frankfurter ball tip beef ribs brisket. Spare ribs frankfurter beef ribs pig flank. Pancetta ball tip t-bone spare ribs brisket. Venison ham short ribs tenderloin, meatloaf biltong doner prosciutto pork leberkas pork chop shank tail chuck.
        </p>
        <p>
Pastrami sausage filet mignon leberkas pork bresaola shank corned beef sirloin. Ham hock salami jerky strip steak capicola sirloin venison filet mignon boudin. Sirloin meatball kielbasa pig, drumstick beef ribs tenderloin shank prosciutto corned beef. Ham hock shankle capicola, sausage meatball strip steak ribeye kielbasa.
        </p>
        <p>
Pancetta capicola sirloin, biltong pork loin chuck turducken boudin. Shoulder hamburger andouille pork loin pork belly chicken. Venison ball tip ground round meatloaf rump cow biltong kielbasa tail capicola flank. Tongue andouille strip steak, venison pork belly ham boudin jowl shank capicola pig shankle. Bacon pastrami pancetta, sausage hamburger chicken shank short loin. Swine fatback short loin, ham filet mignon t-bone turkey jowl prosciutto.
        </p>
    </section>

</div>
```

## JAVASCRIPT

```
$(function() { 
    $('body').scrollspy({target: '#nav_container', offset: 47}); 
    $('#nav_container').on('activate.bs.scrollspy', function() { 
        console.log('sparkle, sparkle');
    });
});
```

## CSS

`section { padding-top: 40px; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'doh

`<li>` did not have the dropdown class.